# Is there a way to lower the complexity of string hash

Tags: string, data-structures, hash

I noticed that many hash functions for strings need to go through the whole string. I can understand that because the information of a string is stored in the whole string.

However, given a string of size n, then the time complexity of the hash function will be `O(n)`, meanwhile, the hash table is expected to do the finding and inserting in `O(1)` complexity.

My question is how does the hash table for strings even work since the hash function itself is `O(n)` already, and whether there are other ways to do string hash.

Comment: If your string hash function needs to walk the entire string, then it's linear complexity in relation to the size of the *string*. Hash table complexity is stated in relation to the size of the *hash table*. Complexity is used to describe how a function scales with respect to the size of a thing. The hash table's size does not affect the complexity.

Comment: If performance matters that much, then you craft a hash function to match 1. your data and 2. your needs. If you noticed that your dataset of strings, on average, was very long but could be easily differentiated by only using the first 20 characters, then you could have a constant-bounded hash function for your string. Most strings are going to be bounded by natural language, anyway -- which is a constant bound on complexity.

Comment: If you start dealing with strings of unbounded size, and that gets in the way of you meeting your design goals, it would be very natural to describe each operation on the hash table in terms of complexity with respect to string size.